# Akka TypedActor with abstract members from trait cause java.lang.AbstractMethodError

Tags: scala, akka, actor, typedactor

Given the following code:

```
import akka.actor._

object TraitTest {
  trait A {
    def something()
  }
  trait B extends A
  class C extends TypedActor with B {
    override def something() {
      println("Why am I not implemented?")
    }
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val service = TypedActor.newInstance(classOf[B], classOf[C]) 
    service.something()
  }
}
```

When running the `main`, I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError: TraitTest$B$$ProxiedByAWDelegation$$1322144340710.something()V
    at TraitTest$.main(TraitTest.scala:29)
    at TraitTest.main(TraitTest.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
```

Now, google finally spat out [this](https://www.assembla.com/spaces/akka/tickets/552-abstractmethoderror-when-invoking-method-not-in-interface-for-typedactor) link, however I don't understand how this 'works as designed'.

Could anybody please shed some light on the issue?

Thanks!

**Edit**
If I change my code as follows, I obviously do not get the error. However, this is of course not a solution, but more a temporary workaround.

```
trait B extends A {
    override def something()
  }
```

Comment: Also experiencing this problem on 2.10.2

Answer (score 0):

We've completely reworked the TypedActor implementation for 2.0 and scrapped using bytecode weaving to implement it. This leads to a much more robust and powerful feature.

Are you running it on jdk7? (we've seen some shenanigans with that)
Can you try to implement the method with the correct signature? (omitted return type == Any, but you override it with Unit-return type)

Cheers,
√

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I was afraid that I will be stuck with this. :) Do you already have a release date for a stable 2.0 version? I would rather not start playing around with SNAPSHOT dependencies... Good to hear that the weaving is out, I am not a big fan of that anyway. My JDK is `1.6.0_29-b11-402-11M3527`, so no shenanigans. :) I'll try the correct override in a minute...

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not help either. :(

Comment: No, there's no release date for the final 2.0 version. But we'll cut a milestone in a couple of weeks.